# PHPUnit: how can you test method with class instantiation?

Tags: phpunit

I have a simple class like:

```
class Subject {
    /** @var ValueObject[] */
    private $collection = [];

    function addToCollection (array $whatver) {
        if (array_key_exists($whatever, 'smth')) {
            $collection[] = new ValueObject($whatever);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know I could simply pass ValueObject to the method, but real life `addToCollection()` is a bit more complex.

Is it at all possible to test this method with PHPUnit or I should redo it with DI in mind?

Thanks

Comment: Sure it is possible to test it, however it is not possible to test it independently. Is `ValueObject` part of your API?

Comment: If you have a getter for the Collection[] you could get it after the `addToCollection` and assert it was created with the right arguments. otherwise you could just assert the response true/false.

Answer (score 3):

In your case I would say it is easy to test this class. 
You have a method that returns bool on success. You don't have any getters or setters so all you need to check is the return value from your method. Everything else is an implementation detail so there is no need to test it.

If you have there dependencies you can mock them through the constructor, but it changes nothig from the perspective of you add method.

Another suggestion is think about single responsibility principle. You are adding something to the collection but also do some magic before you create the object. 
Move the creation of the object to another class (like factory) and keep your class simple - just add the object to the collection. 
With this approach you won't have and dependencies and your code will be easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `ValueObject` instances using an externally injected **Factory**. A default ValueFactory can be created internally if none is injected:

```
class Subject {

    /** @var ValueObject[] */
    private $collection = [];

    /** @var ValueFactory */
    private $valueFactory;

    public function getValueFactory() {
        if (!isset($this->valueFactory)) {
            $this->valueFactory = new ValueFactory();
        }
        return $this->valueFactory;
    }

    public function setValueFactory(ValueFactory $factory) {
        $this->valueFactory = $factory;
    }

    function addToCollection (array $whatever) {
        if (array_key_exists($whatever, 'smth')) {
            $collection[] = 
                $this->getValueFactory()->buildValueObject($parameters);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in your test you can mock a ValueFactory and inject it to Subject, so you can check how instances are created and get control over returned ValueObject instances.